# Altium missing self-made components in SCH Library

Tags: altium

I've been following along a tutorial with Altium and have been making my own components for the schematic and PCB libraries. The schematic library components are missing when I reopened the project, however the PCB components and footprints are still there. The schematic itself can still see the components. See pictures.

[Here's the component library panel to right of schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08IMa.png)

[PCB Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8buZ.png)

[SCH Library with no components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvV9h.png)

I've tried reloading the project, different views, just at a loss here.

Altium version 17.0.10

Comment: Which library did you create them in? That's where you'll find them.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The one listed in the pull down in the schematic image is where I created them. I looked in there and nothing, added it to installed, unloaded/reloaded....no components.

Comment: Did you save the library before closing Altium?

Comment: What Photon said, also it's possible (but usually undesirable) to have libraries of the same name stored in different locations.

Comment: Also, it probably doesn't matter, but you may as well say exactly what version of Altium you're using.

Comment: @Photon Valid question, I'm save happy so I save after finishing each component. Added altium version to question

Answer (score 2):

Best thing I could come up with was to make another Schematic Library from the actual schematic.

1. Drag and drop all components from right side library onto schematic
2. Design -> Make Schematic Library
3. Import new library and delete old

A hacky way of doing it but it works.